# MatrixEntry not iterable when processing CoordinateMatrix... pyspark MLlib

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to execute this line on a CoordinateMatrix...

```
test = test.entries.map(lambda (i, j, v): (j, (i, v)))
```

where the equivalent in Scala seems to work but fails in pyspark.  The error I get when the line is executing...

```
'MatrixEntry' object is not iterable
```

And confirming that I am working with a CoordinateMatrix...

```
>>> test = test_coord.entries
>>> test.first()
>>> MatrixEntry(0, 0, 7.0)
```

Anyone know what might be off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose `test` is a *CoordinatedMatrix*, then:

```
test.entries.map(lambda e: (e.j, (e.i, e.value)))
```

<sub>A side note: you can't unpack a tuple in a lambda function. So `map(lambda (x, y, z): )` is not going to work in this case even though it doesn't seem to be the reason that fails.</sub>

---

*Example*:

```
test = CoordinateMatrix(sc.parallelize([(1,2,3), (4,5,6)]))
test.entries.collect()
# [MatrixEntry(1, 2, 3.0), MatrixEntry(4, 5, 6.0)]
test.entries.map(lambda e: (e.j, (e.i, e.value))).collect()
# [(2L, (1L, 3.0)), (5L, (4L, 6.0))]
```

Comment: thank you!  I thought the variables (i j v) would have to be on the left